# Debugging with Codelite and Cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, codelite

Most of my experience in programming has been with Windows and Visual Studio.  I have been recently looking into cross platform build tools so I can program on Linux as well.  I have been using Cmake to create make files and I figured I would use Codelite as an IDE since it has shortcut keys similar to Visual Studio.  Lucky for me Codelite support as just added with cmake3.0.  I created two small demos just to verify I could compile and debug the program.  I was able to compile the programs easily enough but I ran into issues when trying to debug them.

My project layout looks like this.  Each workspace has it's own CMakeLists.txt and each exe/library has it's own associated CMakeLists.txt also.

```
Workspace1:
  Exe1
     main.cpp
  Exe2
     main2.cpp

Workspace2:
  Library1
     mylib.cpp
     mylib.h
  Exe3
     main.cpp
```

The issue with the first workspace is that I can ONLY debug and run exe1 from inside codelite.  When I set exe2 as the active project and run it, it brings up a blank console window and when I try to debug it I receive the error: "No executable specified, use 'target exec'.

With the second project I can't run anything.  It brings up a blank console window.  I also can't debug the project I receive the same error as before.

Can anyone provide help on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on each project in the file view (usually its the tree on the left side)
and Select `Settings`
In the project settings dialog that appears, navigate to (it should be the first page by default): `Common Settings -> General`
Under the **Execution** section select the executable to Run/Debug

See attached screenshot.
Do this for all the projects

[image]

HTH,

Eran